# How to fix Unterminated expression in f-string; missing close brace in python?

Tags: python

I want to use f string formatting instead of print. However, I get these errors:
Unterminated expression in f-string; missing close brace
Expected ')'

```
var="ab-c"
f"{var.replace("-","")}text123"
```

I tried to use single quote f'' and also double brackets but neither of them worked. Any idea about how to fix this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Before Python 3.12:**

For `f"{var.replace("-","")}text123"`, Python parses `f"{var.replace("` as a complete string, which you can see has an opening `{` and opening `(`, but then the string is terminated.  It first expected a `)` and eventually a `}`, hence the error you see.

To fix it, Python allows `'` or `"` to enclose a string, so use one for the f-string and the other for inside the string:

```
f"{var.replace('-','')}text123"
```

or:

```
f'{var.replace("-","")}text123'
```

Triple quotes can also be used if internally you have both `'` and `"`

```
f'''{var.replace("-",'')}text123'''
```

or:

```
f"""{var.replace("-",'')}text123"""
```

**As of Python 3.12:**

Some f-string limitations have been lifted and the OP's original code now works:

```py
Python 3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2 2023, 13:03:39) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> var="ab-c"
>>> f"{var.replace("-","")}text123"
'abctext123'
```

See [What's New in Python 3.12, PEP 701: Syntactic formalization of f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#whatsnew312-pep701).

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes:

```
var="ab-c"
f'{var.replace("-","")}text123'

# display abctext123
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var = "ab-c"
f"{var.replace('-','')}text123"
```

always use a different quote character than the ones inside the f-string